# DataGridView design X scroll with fixed header, visible grid line, even column width

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, datagridview

I'm making an admin panel and I have DataGridView on each page.

At the moment, it is not showing x &y gridLines and column width is arbitrary. I've used ItemStyle width 10%, but still doesn't really do the trick.

Here is my source code

```
<td class="auto-style9" colspan="2">
    <div style= "Overflow:scroll; overflow-x: scroll; max-height: 220px; width: auto">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewUpPer" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SubCatID" HeaderText="Sub category ID">
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:BoundField>
```

Here is my design

[image: my ugly GV]

x scroll is not appearing and my gridView is not showing the entire columns. I only can change heard text color not the text color of data. I'm using table and div.

I have 15 of GV looking like this..... Can anyone help me to design a good looking gridView?? Without using java coz I'm new to programming and I don't know that script language...... Thanks~

C#, VS 2012, web application